# Excel 2007: Change background color cells ->not based on value of cell

Tags: excel-2007

Is possible to change background without based on value of cell?

So for example, all blue cells on Sheet change to red.

Conditional formatting does not allow this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this via Find/Replace.
Just leave the text values for **`Find what`** and **`Replace with`** empty and rather select a format.

[Image of settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cL1E.png)